# Resume from suspend requires hard reset

Tags: 14.04, ati, power-management, suspend

Most of the threads I've found relating to this problem state that the machine powers up but the screen remains black. Not so in my case.

The problem I am experiencing is this. When testing the Suspend, everything works as expected. Computer enters sleep and I can resume from USB. But testing is usually for a short duration. When I leave the Computer in sleep for any length of time (shortest I've noticed but may be less is 1 hour) it will not wake up or power up. I do notice the LED on my case fan flash once, but other than that there is nothing. So, of course, there are no error logs.

In addition to this, the reset button does not work neither does holding the power button. I have to physically cut the power, after which I can do a normal reboot.

I'm on a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04, with a Radeon HD6790 graphics card. Thinking it may be related to the graphics card I've tried both the Catalyst v.12 and the beta v.14.

All I can think is that it must be some setting used to enter Suspend which is causing the problem.

Can anybody suggest a way to remedy the problem or something else I can try?

Comment: I was also having a similar issue, this is a bug as mentioned by Bain in the answer. You should report this issue so future versions for your specific case can be solved. Good day Waldermort ^^.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and should be reported it on Launchpad. You will then be asked to:

- Update all of your packages (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)
- [Upgrade your BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BiosUpdate) if an upgrade is available.
- [Try the very latest mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds) to verify the bug has not already been fixed.
- Follow the instructions at [DebuggingKernelSuspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend) and [Kernel Documentation: Debugging hibernation and suspend](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt)

Even if the bug is fixed in later mainline Linux kernels, it is still important to report the issue on Launchpad to ensure that the bug gets fixed in the Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: I've just been reading the DebuggingKernel link. Trouble is I have to wait a long time while PC is sleeping to see the problem. All I can do is sleep using the given command and try in the mornings.

Comment: Yes, debugging these kind of intermittent faults requires time and patience. What make/model system is this? Does the BIOS have any "deep sleep" or other sleep related features? Does the issue still occur if you suspend from a text only boot (add "text" to the kernel parameters in grub)? If this is a desktop you can also try swapping out hardware components to try and narrow down exactly which component triggers the fail (most likely would be the motherboard, GPU). Also try a serial console if you can, the kernel might be trying to print an error but if GPU fails you can not see it.

Comment: Well, just booted into the latest kernel and I have no desktop or any terminal or keys. Had to hit the reset button :/ To answer your question, there is nothing special in the BIOS and it's updated. I'll just keep putting the machine to sleep using `pm_trace` and hopefully I can at least confirm it is the GPU. I'll report these two bugs and hopefully they have a solution waiting for beta testing.